# Digit sum of certain number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a piece of code that generates the digit sum of numbers and prints them ONLY IF they are multiples of 5.

So, for example: 0, 5, and 14 would be the first three digits that print out in this instance.

```
num = 0
while num < 100:
    sums = sum([int(digit) for digit in str(num)]) 
    if sums % 5 == 0: #determines if the sum is a multiple of 5
        print(num)
    num += 1
```

And this code works great! Definitely gets the job done for the sums between 1 and 100. However, I don't have a ton of experience in python and figured I'd push myself and try and get it done in one line of code instead.

Currently, this is what I'm working with:

```
print(sum(digit for digit in range(1,100) if digit % 5 == 0))
```

I feel like I'm somewhere along the right track, but I can't get the rest of the way there. Currently, this code is spitting out 950.

I know that `digit % 5 == 0` is totally wrong, but I'm all out of ideas! Any help and/or words of wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not summing the digits in your second example (you're summing the numbers themselves)...

Comment: @ValentinM. Not quite, it's summing the numbers 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95

Comment: You said `0+5+14+19+23...` which would give a sum of 990; not the 950 that the OP was getting.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Indeed, that's a miscalculation on my side, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work for me

```
print([digit for digit in range(1,100) if (sum([int(i) for i in str(digit)]) % 5==0)])
```

or if you want to include the 0:

```
print([digit for digit in range(0,100) if (sum([int(i) for i in str(digit)]) % 5==0)])
```

Comment: Aha! I was just summing everything up in the wrong location. This makes a ton more sense. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you were summing the total of ALL the digits, not the individual digits of the number

Comment: Just a little nitpick... the `digit` variable is actually the number itself (from `range`), and the `i` variable is the digits of the number you're considering...

Answer (score 3):

With less parenthesis etc.:

```
>>> [n for n in range(100) if sum(int(d) for d in str(n)) % 5 == 0]
[0, 5, 14, 19, 23, 28, 32, 37, 41, 46, 50, 55, 64, 69, 73, 78, 82, 87, 91, 96]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a one-liner (I think your current solution is more readable):

```
print(*(i for i in range(101) if sum(int(j) for j in str(i))%5 == 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use two nested list comprehensions: one will generate a list of tuples of numbers and their sums of digits, and the other will select those that meet your condition:

```
[num for num,s in 
    [(x, sum(int(digit) for digit in str(x))) # The inner one
     for x in range(100)] 
 if s % 5 == 0]
#[0, 5, 14, 19, 23, 28, 32, 37, 41, 46, 50, 55, 64...]
```

Other solutions are possible, too.

Answer (score 0):

Adding long code for readability,

```
#separating each digits within number
def sum_digits(number):
    res = 0
    for x in str(number): res += int(x)
    return res

num_list = []   
for number in range(0, 100):
    if sum_digits(number) % 5 == 0:
         num_list.append(number)
         
print(num_list)
```

gives

```
[0, 5, 14, 19, 23, 28, 32, 37, 41, 46, 50, 55, 64, 69, 73, 78, 82, 87, 91, 96]
```